# Debugging _crypt unicode error in compiled Python 3.6 --with-pydebug

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, utf-8, crypt

I have compiled Python 3.6 but something went wrong so that the following code fails

```
Python 3.6.0+ (default, Feb 25 2017, 12:10:05)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import _crypt
>>> _crypt.crypt('', '')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfb in position 1: invalid start byte
```

Where should I look to debug it?

---

Update:

```
>>> sys.path
['', 
 '/Users/andrei/Python/installed/lib/python36.zip',
 '/Users/andrei/Python/installed/lib/python3.6', 
 '/Users/andrei/Python/installed/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', 
 '/Users/andrei/Python/installed/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
```

---

Update:

```
building '_crypt' extension
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -O0 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -I./Include -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/Users/andrei/Python/cpython/Include -I/Users/andrei/Python/cpython -c /Users/andrei/Python/cpython/Modules/_cryptmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.12-x86_64-3.6-pydebug/Users/andrei/Python/cpython/Modules/_cryptmodule.o
gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include build/temp.macosx-10.12-x86_64-3.6-pydebug/Users/andrei/Python/cpython/Modules/_cryptmodule.o -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o build/lib.macosx-10.12-x86_64-3.6-pydebug/_crypt.cpython-36dm-darwin.so
building '_csv' extension
```

Nothing looks wrong with `_crypt` extension...

---

Update:

```
$ ./python.exe -m test -j6 test_crypt
Run tests in parallel using 6 child processes
0:00:00 [1/1] test_crypt passed
1 test OK.

Total duration: 447 ms
Tests result: SUCCESS
```

---

Update: Problem is gone when I remove `--with-pydebug`.

Comment: Works for me. Please show the output of `sys.path`.

Comment: @kennytm Well, I am starting to get an idea what is wrong... :) _Edit: Hm, vanilla 3.6.0 has similar path. There may be some conflict between compiled Python and pyenv, not sure..._

Comment: If you have got the solution, feel free to add a self-answer :) The sys.path looks normal, so the error probably is due to your `lib-dynload/_crypt.cpython-36m-darwin.so` being corrupt.

Comment: @kennytm Ok, that's not what I was hoping for :) Any idea what can make _crypt to corrupt?

Comment: @kennytm it was something with `--with-pydebug`. Removing that parameter "fixed" the problem.